# tag badge counters not recording votes

Tags: bug, tag-badges

I have noticed that one of my tag badge counters (xsd) has stopped recording votes.

This is very annoying.

It's been stuck on 96 despite at least 4 votes and an awarded answer on questions for that tag in the past few days.